# How do I define products with only specific property tags (Spree, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I've got a custom Spree app.  I need to query Spree::Products that have the associated Spree::Property

I have a 'property' with the name "Rating" on only certain products, but I can't query those products correctly.  What I have now is:

```
Spree::Product.joins(:properties).where(:property_name.downcase == "rating")
```

but that just pulls all the products that have any :properties associated with them at all.

Spree::Property -

```
Spree::Property(id: integer, name: string, presentation: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on Spree 3.1. You can do that from Product or Property model.

```
Spree::Product.joins(:properties).where(spree_properties: {name: "rating"})
```

or

```
Spree::Property.where(name: "rating").first.products
```

*You have to modify the code to use downcase string.